# problem with page count in pressflow & varnish

Tags: caching, 6, proxies

i'm using pressflow &  varnish & cashrouter in my site.
my problem is node counter is not true because google analytic show diffrent count of node.
for example in google analytic show count of node is 12000 but in pressflow show 300 hint.
im using revers proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This module should take care if it for you
http://drupal.org/project/jstats

For other options see the Performance wiki and look (ctrl-f) for `Statistics`
http://groups.drupal.org/node/187209

Comment: i'm using jstats but this module can not help me

Comment: Open an issue in the issue queue letting the dev know why it won't work for you. http://drupal.org/project/issues/jstats